# How to read in csv correctly with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv-file which looks like this:

```
A B C
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 1 2 3 4 5
```

When I read in this file using this code:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path\to\file.csv',delimiter=';')
```

I get a pandas dataframe which exist of three columns named A, B and C.
The first five rows of my actual csv file are taken as index and the last two rows are stated in column A and B and in C I only get NaN values.

Instead I would like to get a dataframe with columns A, B and C as the first three columns and the rest Unnamed columns. I think it is maybe due to a formatting issue with my csv-file but I do not know hwo to solve this..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't see any `;` in your csv, why are you using it as the delimiter character?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with blank space as suggested as delimiter and without any delimiter but it did not work. That is the reason why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'path\to\file.csv',delimiter=' ', names=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'], skiprows=1,index_col=False)
```

Comment: `]` missing in usecolumns.

Comment: Tnx for noticing. Fixed that

Comment: Yes, I got a vlaue error and I had to use delimiter `;`.

Comment: See my updated answer above. If ; works for you better then change it

Comment: Ok, `names` is better, thanks! And I had to add `index_col=False` in order to get the first column not as index. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes. If you want to avoid the extra column